# Really dont know who start

Tags: fiware-cygnus

I install Cygnus from RPM repository like [this](http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-common/installation_and_administration_guide/install_with_rpm/index.html) and now i dont know how continue.

I try continue whit [this section](http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-common/installation_and_administration_guide/running_as_process/index.html) and i got the following error:

```
bash: APACHE_FLUME_HOME/bin/cygnus-flume-ng: No such file or directory
```

I am really confused about documentation, because i restart 3 times at start when i try to use docker image, the image got so much errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need java, maven and Flume correctly installed before starting.

`export APACHE_FLUME_HOME_BIN=/usr/local/flume` to your shell

I recommend following the [install from source](http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-common/installation_and_administration_guide/install_from_sources/index.html), which guide you through all the steps.

For docker start with the [cygnus-common Dockerfile](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/docker/cygnus-common/Dockerfile) which uses centos6 as base.

Comment: OK, thanx, now i start the docker image on my rancher and now... where should i continue?

Comment: You need to change the config in the Dockerfile so it fits your setup. can you connect to port 5050 and 8081 on the container?, change LOG_LEVEL to DEBUG. also look at flume agent.conf. Also log in interactively on /bin/bash. google debugging docker containers should give you some ideas :-)

Comment: Thanx again, now i can connect to ports. Now i must start conect orion boker and cygnus  and learn who makes cygnus connecto whit ckan and sth commet